# Как лучше стилизовать react компоненты?

Tags: reactjs

Пока временно сделал так:
http://prntscr.com/mgc44m
у каждого компонента свои стили, который импортируются в сам компонент. 
CSS модули не понравились тем, что потом получаются грязные названия классов. Что ещё можете порекомендовать?

Answer (score 1):

Ваш вариант считается официальным [Best Practice](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-structure.html), поэтому я не вижу смысла Вам что то менять.

Также из лидеров можно отметить:

- [styled components](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics) подход, в котором файлы CSS отсутствуют как таковые
- [CSS-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) - работа со стилями похожа на работу с JS объектами

Comment: А что можете сказать о таком подходе https://codesandbox.io/s/ox9kzol945 (MyComponents)? Я изучаю `React` совместно с `Material UI` и мне такой подход показался довольно удобным. Хорошая это практика или плохая?

Comment: `MyCompoents.js` - пустой файл

Comment: Исправил, должно работать

Comment: @RomanAndreev Вам тогда лучше использовать [CSS-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules). Они делают тоже самое, но не нужно дополнительных функций `withStyles` и стили лежат в CSS файлах. Добавил в ответ и этот вариант. Спасибо за подсказку

Comment: А на сколько строго в мире разработчиков реакта принято следовать тому стилю что вы указали как `best-practice`? Я только начинаю вкатываться в реакт, и мне весьма понравился предложенный вами вариант `styled-components`, когда файлов стиля вообще нету.  Косо смотреть за такое не будут ? :)

Comment: @RomanAndreev вопрос риторический. Всё что является Best Practice сейчас, когда то таковым не было. `styled-components` - очень популярный подход, со своими плюсами и минусами. "Косо смотреть не будут?" - я буду, потому что мне субьективно не нравится это смешивание всего в один файл, но на меня найдется другой разработчик, который будет косо смотреть на меня)) так что решать Вам и коллегам по проекту